# Netty Http Client - Configure DNSResolution timeout

Tags: netty, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I am getting this error with WebClient. This is expected as per my configuration. But how to configure the timeout for dns name resolution via netty http client?

```
Caused by: io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverTimeoutException: [/127.0.0.11:53] query via UDP timed out after 5000 milliseconds (no stack trace available)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, DNS query timeout is 5 sec ([DEFAULT_QUERY_TIMEOUT](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/72f88aafd0647efac43b20ca37d1c899b11d488a/reactor-netty-core/src/main/java/reactor/netty/transport/NameResolverProvider.java#L560)) but you could customize underlining Netty `HttpClient` if required

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .resolver(spec -> spec.queryTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10)));

WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .build();
```